# emacs for submodule of installed package that hosted on github

Tags: emacs, github

I have installed emacs on several computers, and to sync the configurations between them, i setup a github repo that stores my emacs configurations, i.e., my folder ~/.emacs.d

now, i started to use emacs on one computer, i installed certain package, lets say, package_foo, using MELPA. Now there is a folder called package_foo in my .emacs.d/elpa foder. i also found the package_foo actually is actually hosted on github. it would be great if i can submodule it because my .emacs.d is on github as well.

so if package_foo i installed by emacs package manager is on github, how can i submodule it automatically instead of copy it to my .emacs.d/elpa folder? Is there an emacs plugin that knows the source of package_foo, and submodule it for installation (if possible) instead of pulling all files? That can not only save space on github, but also save my bandwidth when syncing.

Comment: I don't think there's any github-aware plugin for elpa.  My advice? Don't use elpa.  I much prefer to use git submodules.  See https://github.com/magnars/.emacs.d/ for a great example.  Another option would be to look at el-get: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/el-get

Comment: @Rob ELPA gives you a proper `load-path` and autoloads for free.  With Git submodules you have to do this for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use submodules for packages.  Don't commit packages to your repository.

Instead, configure Emacs to automatically install missing packages for you.  You can either use some special function for this purpose:

```
(defun package-required (package) (unless (package-installed-p package) (package-install package))

(package-required 'magit)
```

Or you can use [Carton](https://github.com/rejeep/carton) to manage your packages by declaring them in a `Carton` file.  Then you can use the shell commands `carton install` to install missing packages, and `carton update` to update all packages.

Comment: If you're not going to commit packages to your own repository, you may wish to specify the exact version of each package that you wish to use, rather than asking for the latest version and assuming it'll work fine. It you *do* commit your packages, roll-back after a problematic update is absolutely trivial. Personally I recommend doing it, but YMMV.

Comment: @lunaryorn your function package-required gives error:＂if: Symbol's value as variable is void: package＂

Comment: @shelper I have a hard time believing that.  Did you copy the snippet correctly?